# Problema con dependencias - Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con Spring Boot (debo decir que estoy empezando) y se me presenta el siguiente caso.

Tengo un proyecto `ProjectA` que contiene un repositorio. Por otro lado tengo otro proyecto `ProjectB` que hace uso del repositorio del `ProjectA`.

```
+---ProjectA
|---+ src
    |---+ com
        |---+ exampleA
            |----- ControllerA.java
            |----- ServiceA.java
            |----- RepositoryA.java

+---ProjectB
    |---+ src
        |---+ com
            |---+ exampleB
                |----- ControllerB.java
                |----- ServiceB.java
                |----- RepositoryB.java
```

En `RepositoryB.java`, tengo un `@Autowired private RepositoryA repositoryA;`

En el `pom.xml` de `ProjectB` tengo añadida la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Pero no puede importar el repositorio en `@Autowired private RepositoryA repositoryA;` del `RepositoryB.java`.

He intentado poner `@ComponentScan` con el paquete del `RepositoryA.java` y sigue sin funcionar.

Sabéis qué me está faltando?

Gracias por adelantado,

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has declarado (anotado) RepositoryA como `@Repository`?

Comment: Sí, pero tampoco me da opción de importar el paquete

Comment: ¿Qué paquete no puedes importar?

Comment: El com.example.RepositoryA.java. Tengo el `@Autowired private RepositoryA repositoryA;` y si pincho encima, me lleva a la clase del `ProjectA`, pero no puede resolver el import

Comment: Eclipse a veces se lía con Maven, has probado a pulsar Ctrl+F5, teniendo seleccionado el proyecto B en el árbol? Eso debería refrescar Maven y sus dependencias

Comment: También lo he probado... sin resultado. Te cuento lo que tengo ahora por si te ayuda a saber por dónde puede ir. Tengo marcado el repositorio A con `@Repository` y la dependencia en el `pom.xml` del B. Simplemente con eso debería poder importar `com.exampleA.RepositoryA` o tendría que añadir alguna notación más en alguna otra clase?

Comment: Por qué no creas ese repository en el proyecto A como propio, si vas directo al repository significa que no necesitas las reglas de negocio del proyecto B, y le das la conexión de ambas bases (si es que son distintas).

Comment: El `RepositoryA` lo uso tanto en el `ProjectA`como en el `ProjectB`

Comment: Ya corriste `mvn clean install` en el proyectoA?

Comment: Sí, he hecho `mvn clean install`en el A y en el B. Añadiendo `@ComponentScan` y `@EnableMongoRepositories` he conseguido importar el repositorio de A en B, pero al hacer `mvn clean deploy` da el error `package com.exampleA does not exist
cannot find symbol`

Comment: Si los proyectos están relacionados... por qué no lo haces un proyecto maven multimódulo?